# How to compare two tables in Sybase ASE 15.7

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

AS captioned,I need to compare two tables to check the difference, these two tables are the same structure but have different row count and data discrepancy for columns.

Comment: What do you want to compare ? the structure ? but you are saying it has the same strucute. you want to compare what does exists and not exists ?

Comment: @Moudiz ,I want compare the data count and whether there exists data differerence for  some column

Comment: do you want something like this ? `select id, name from tab1 t1 where not exists ( select * from tab2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id)`

Comment: @Moudiz ,yes,but besides, I want to compare each column if the item exists in both table

Comment: @Moudiz ,about 80 columns

Comment: It's hard to use, but Sybase has the rs_subcmp utility:   It runs two select statements against each table and then joins the two streams in the client.  It can even handle transient differences that might occur when comparing replicated data.  Be careful with the -h "fast"

Comment: Also, if your tables aren't too big and you're using Linux, bcp them out to files and use   

"diff -wydt --suppress-common"  

to diff the files (diff side-by-side, ignoring spaces, suppressing lines with no diffs)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem.

Wrote this stored proc:

```
/*
**Author: Martin Bartscher
**Find & give out differences between two, 'same' Tables with old and new data.
*/
create or replace proc mb_diff_old_new_table(
 @table_old varchar(255) /*table with the old data*/
 ,@table_new varchar(255) /*table with the new data*/
 ,@identifier_columns varchar(16384) /*names of the columns, that identify a data set; have to be separated by a single comma*/
 ,@columns_to_compare varchar(16384) /*names of the columns, that shall be compared; have to be separated by a single comma*/
 ,@debug bit =0
)
as begin
 /*
 **declare variables
 */
 declare @sql varchar(16384)
  ,@sql_ident_cols_on varchar(16384)
  ,@sql_comp_cols_where varchar(16384)
  ,@sql_select_out_both varchar(16384)
  ,@sql_where_old_null varchar(16384)
  ,@sql_where_new_null varchar(16384)
  ,@id_cols varchar(16384)
  ,@comp_cols varchar(16384)
  ,@cur_col varchar(255)
  ,@crlf char(2)
  ,@rows_diff_old int
  ,@rows_diff_new int
  ,@com_pos int
 /*
 **initialize variables
 */
 set @sql=null
 set @sql_ident_cols_on='on ('
 set @sql_comp_cols_where='where '
 set @sql_select_out_both='select '
 set @sql_where_old_null='where ot.'
 set @sql_where_new_null='where nt.'
 set @id_cols=@identifier_columns
 set @comp_cols=@columns_to_compare
 set @cur_col=null
 set @crlf=char(13)+char(10)
 set @rows_diff_old=0
 set @rows_diff_new=0
 set @com_pos=0
 /*
 **clean up old res-tables if proc ran before
 */
 if exists(select name from sysobjects where name='mb_diff_old') begin
  drop table mb_diff_old
 end
 if exists(select name from sysobjects where name='mb_diff_new') begin
  drop table mb_diff_new
 end
 /*
 **build 'on' clause with data set identifying columns
 */
 while len(@id_cols)>0 begin
  set @com_pos=charindex(',',@id_cols)
  if @com_pos!=0 begin
   set @cur_col=left(@id_cols,@com_pos-1)
   set @id_cols=substring(@id_cols,@com_pos+1,len(@id_cols)-@com_pos)
  end
  else begin
   set @cur_col=@id_cols
   set @id_cols=null
  end
  set @sql_ident_cols_on=@sql_ident_cols_on+'ot.'+@cur_col+'=nt.'+@cur_col+@crlf
  set @sql_select_out_both=@sql_select_out_both+'ot.'+@cur_col
  if @id_cols!=null begin
   set @sql_ident_cols_on=@sql_ident_cols_on+' and '
   set @sql_select_out_both=@sql_select_out_both+','
  end
  else begin
   set @sql_ident_cols_on=@sql_ident_cols_on+')'
   set @sql_select_out_both=@sql_select_out_both+' /*identificational columns*/'+@crlf
   set @sql_where_old_null=@sql_where_old_null+@cur_col+'=null'
   set @sql_where_new_null=@sql_where_new_null+@cur_col+'=null'
  end
 end
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'on-clause: '
  print @sql_ident_cols_on
  print 'select_out_both: '
  print @sql_select_out_both
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 /*
 **build 'where' clause with the columns with the values to compare
 */
 while len(@comp_cols)>0 begin
  set @com_pos=charindex(',',@comp_cols)
  if @com_pos!=0 begin
   set @cur_col=left(@comp_cols,@com_pos-1)
   set @comp_cols=substring(@comp_cols,@com_pos+1,len(@comp_cols)-@com_pos)
  end
  else begin
   set @cur_col=@comp_cols
   set @comp_cols=null
  end
  set @sql_comp_cols_where=@sql_comp_cols_where+'ot.'+@cur_col+'!=nt.'+@cur_col+@crlf
  set @sql_select_out_both=@sql_select_out_both+
   ',ot.'+@cur_col+' as '+@cur_col+'_alt, nt.'+@cur_col+' as '+@cur_col+'_neu'
  if @comp_cols!=null begin
   set @sql_comp_cols_where=@sql_comp_cols_where+' or '
   set @sql_select_out_both=@sql_select_out_both+@crlf
  end
 end
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'where-clause: '
  print @sql_comp_cols_where
  print 'select_out_both: '
  print @sql_select_out_both
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 /*
 **all data rows from old table, without equivalent data row in new table 
 */
 set @sql='select ot.*
  into mb_diff_old
  from '+@table_old+' ot
  left join '+@table_new+' nt
  '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
  '+@sql_where_new_null
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'all data rows from old table, without equivalent data row in new table'
  print @sql
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 /*
 **all data rows from new table, without equivalent data row in old table 
 */
 set @sql= 'select nt.*
  into mb_diff_new
  from '+@table_old+' ot
  right join '+@table_new+' nt
  '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
  '+@sql_where_old_null
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'all data rows from new table, without equivalent data row in old table'
  print @sql
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 /*
 **all data rows from old table, with difference to new table
 */
 set @sql='insert into mb_diff_old
  select ot.*
  from '+@table_old+' ot
  join '+@table_new+' nt
  '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
  '+@sql_comp_cols_where
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'all data rows from old table, with difference to new table'
  print @sql
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 /*
 **all data rows from new table, with difference to old table
 */
 set @sql='insert into mb_diff_new
  select nt.*
  from '+@table_old+' ot
  join '+@table_new+' nt
  '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
  '+@sql_comp_cols_where
 if @debug=1 begin
  print 'all data rows from new table, with difference to old table'
  print @sql
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 --------------------------------output--------------------------------
 /*
 **check if differences and put them out
 */
 set @sql='select @rows_diff_old=count(*) from mb_diff_old'
 if @debug=1 begin
  print "Can't determine '@rows_diff_old', because 'mb_diff_old' won't be created in debug mode."
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 /*
 **If I write this (two) statement(s) directly, the parser thinks of it as a
 **mistake, because 'mb_diff_(old/new)' isn't existing when I create the proc...
 */
 set @sql='select @rows_diff_new=count(*) from mb_diff_new'
 if @debug=1 begin
  print "Can't determine '@rows_diff_new', because 'mb_diff_new' won't be created in debug mode."
  print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
 end
 else begin
  exec (@sql)
 end
 /*
 **output only if there are differences
 */
 if @rows_diff_old!=0 or @rows_diff_new!=0 or @debug=1 begin
  /*
  **All data sets, that are only in the old results.
  */
  set @sql='select "All data sets, that are only in the old results." as "result description" 
   select ot.* 
   from mb_diff_old ot
   left join mb_diff_new nt
   '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
   '+@sql_where_new_null
  if @debug=1 begin
   print 'All data sets, that are only in the old results.'
   print @sql
   print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
  end
  else begin
   exec (@sql)
  end
  /*
  **All data sets, that are only in the new results.
  */
  set @sql='select "All data sets, that are only in the new results." as "result description"
   select nt.* 
   from mb_diff_old ot
   right join mb_diff_new nt
   '+@sql_ident_cols_on+'
   '+@sql_where_old_null
  if @debug=1 begin
   print 'All data sets, that are only in the new results.'
   print @sql
   print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
  end
  else begin
   exec (@sql)
  end
  /*
  **All data sets, that are in both results, but differ.
  */
  set @sql='select "All data sets, that are in both results, but differ." as "result description"
  '+@sql_select_out_both+'
   from mb_diff_old ot
   join mb_diff_new nt
   '+@sql_ident_cols_on
  if @debug=1 begin
   print 'All data sets, that are in both results, but differ.'
   print @sql
   print '----------------------------------------------------------------'
  end
  else begin
   exec (@sql)
  end
 end
 /*
 **output that no differences were found
 */
 else begin
  select 'There are no differences.' as 'result description'
 end
end
```